# C# - displaying lots of text in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be able to display process update information to a user.  The way I want to do this is by having a control on the main winform that (at a yet undecided process) keeps the user informed via text of what the status is.  I want this text to scrollup (within a control) as more text is added.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a multiline TextBox, like so:

```
myTextBox.Multiline = true;
```

And update it while scrolling to the bottom, like so:

```
myTextBox.Text += "My message" + System.Environment.NewLine;
myTextBox.SelectionStart = myTextBox.Text.Length;
myTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, a multiline TextBox or RichTextBox will do the job just fine.  Use its AppendText() method.

I cannot judge the value of this info from your question.  In general, avoid assuming the user is interested in implementation details, especially when there's a lot of it.  A ProgressBar is almost always the most appropriate progress indicator.  Maybe a Label or a StatusStrip to give some context.

Beware of the cost of Control.BeginInvoke() to update the controls.